# Nested view not receiving data from controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

From the documentation the way we pass data from controller to view in laravel is like

```
return view('someview')->with('key', $data);
```

So I try to pass my query results to view by

```
$data = DB::table('user')->where('confirmation_status',1)->get();
return view('admin.presidentConfirmed')->with('data',$data);
```

But at the presidentConfirmed view, there's no data in it.
So I tried to use `{{ Session::all() }}` to see if there's anything in the session.

Nothing...

So I tried passing just plain text through with

`return view('admin.presidentConfirmed')->with('test','value');`

Still nothing...

It's seems to only happen to only this specific view. Since I use `->with()` with many other views without any problem.

**presidentConfirmed**

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

@stop
```

**layout.main**

```
@include('layout/component.menu')

<div class="container" id="main_container">
  <div class="well">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
  @if(Config::get('app.debug') == true)
    <div class="well">
      {{ var_dump(Session::all()) }}
    </div>
  @endif
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@yield('script')
@if(Config::get('applicationConfig.release') == 'release' && Config::get('applicationConfig.mode') != 'close' && Config::get('applicationConfig.mode') != 'technical_difficulties')
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-73122311-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out, it's actually me that confused `->with()` that use with `Redirect::` and `->with()` that use with `view()`

`Redirect::to('/somepage')->with('key','value)` is the one that stores its data in a session and use `Session::get('key')` to retrieve the data.

`view('someview')->with('key','value')` doesn't store its data in a session and retrieve the data with `{{ $key }}`

Answer (score 1):

**From laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views)** :

> Of course, views may also be nested within sub-directories of the
>   `resources/views` directory. For example, if your view is stored at
>   `resources/views/admin/profile.php`, it should be returned like so:

```
return view('admin.profile', $data);
```

So,in your case it should be :

```
return view('admin.presidentConfirmed',$data);
```

Comment: can you please post the result of var_dump($data) ??

Comment: By the way I try die(var_dump($data)) and it's not empty

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#170 (10) { ["student_id"]=> int(52170) ["title"]=> string(9) "Mr" ["fname"]=> string(21) "test" ["lname"]=> string(39) "test" ["national_id"]=> string(13) "1234567891123" ["class"]=> int(77) ["room"]=> int(655) ["number"]=> int(33) ["current_club"]=> string(8) "a30927" ["confirmation_status"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: did you check your error_log file ?? You must be getting some error

Comment: I did and there's not a single error.
Also the page renders as usual.